# HTML Search button - Identify & Interact with only tag name and value

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am writing a bit of code to enter text into the search bar of http://www.boxofficemojo.com/ and then hit "search".  I can input the appropriate text into the search bar but am having trouble actually clicking the link.  Here is my code:

```
Dim objIE As New InternetExplorer 
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim oSearch As HTMLDivElement
Dim SearchElements As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim SearchButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/"
        Do While objIE.Busy Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Set Doc = objIE.Document
End With

Set oSearch = Doc.forms("searchbox").elements("q")
    oSearch.Value = "Rogue One"
Set SearchElements = Doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each SearchButton In SearchElements
            If SearchButton.Value = "search..." Then
            SearchButton.Click
            End If
        Exit For
            Next SearchButton
```

Any ideas?  I've experimented with doc.forms(3).submit but that seems inconsistent - sometimes it navigates me to the wrong webpage.

Comment: "search..." is not equal to "Search..."

Comment: tip #2: "search..." is equal to lcase("Search...")

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working for some reason.  WHen I make that change IE navigates to a google search for: [*object HTMLInputElement].  I must be not be defining the SearchElements tag correctly right?